# Make Jira Issue Collector popup draggable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, jira, jira-agile

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to make my company's Jira Issue Collector popup draggable. Many users of a particular site we're developing have complained that this feature is overly-cumbersome to use, since one must close the popup to see the underlying page and hence the error that they want to report.

I thought I could simply wrap the generated source in a Kendo UI Window, but alas, there are many supplementary scripts and CSS files that must be loaded for the popup to render correctly. Trying to make the contents of these local to our site has proved to be basically impossible, due to the sheer amount of code they contain, and the fact that the popup is rendered in an iframe.

So how might we be able to go about this? MTIA :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would also like to find an answer to that... I've been trying all the jQuery tricks I could find, to no avail. There are a few feature requests open at Atlassian for similar features, like making the collector window resizable, or making certain fields required. Guess we'll have to wait for a new Jira release  ; )

Comment: Yeah waiting for a new release, and telling users to be patient, seems like the only solution unfortunately :-(